# Titanium can't remove child view

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-alloy

I have a `ScrollView` which I am adding multiple `View`'s into using this code:

```
payload = {
    booking : b,
    duration: duration,
    removeBooking: function(view_to_remove) {
        removeBooking(view_to_remove);
    },
    updateBooking: function(view_to_remove, new_booking) {
        removeBooking(view_to_remove);
        overlayBooking(new_booking);
    }
};

booking = Alloy.createController('appointments_bookable_booking', payload).getView(); // returns a View
$.intervals_container.add(booking); // this is adding a View into a ScrollView
...
```

`removeBooking()` then gets executed later on as a callback. I am then trying to remove the single `View` like this:

```
function removeBooking(booking_view) {

    for (var i = $.intervals_container.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(booking_view === $.intervals_container.children[i]) {
            Ti.API.info('Found a match');
            $.intervals_container.remove($.intervals_container.children[i]);
        }
    };

}
```

I'm looping through the children just to show the view I'm trying to remove DOES actually exist in the children views array. I do get the 'Found a match' printed to my console but the view is never actually removed.

There are other views being added into the `ScrollView` as well. If I loop through the `intervals_container.children` and remove each one. The other views are removed apart from the ones created using the code above.

Can anyone see why I can't remove the view?

**UPDATE**

After trying ericfreshz'a answer I can remove ALL the views however this is not working to remove one:

```
if ($.intervals_container.children) {
        var _viewCount = $.intervals_container.children.length;
        for ( s = 0; s < _viewCount; s++) {
            if($.intervals_container.children[((_viewCount - 1) - s)] === booking_view) {
                Ti.API.info('Removing view');
                $.intervals_container.remove($.intervals_container.children[((_viewCount - 1) - s)]);
            }
    }
}
```

This should only remove the view which has been passed into the function but it doesn't. I get "Removing view" in my console but the view isn't removed.

**UPDATE 2**

I did an experiment to see if the scrollview was actually changed and it turns out the view is actually removed as the number of children views actually decreases however the view is still visible.

```
Ti.API.info('Count BEFORE: ' + $.intervals_container.children.length);

$.intervals_container.remove(booking_view);

Ti.API.info('Count AFTER: ' + $.intervals_container.children.length);
```

The result is one less.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try my code as below :

```
if ($.intervals_container.children) {
   var _viewCount = $.intervals_container.children.length;
   for ( s = 0; s < _viewCount; s++) {
        $.intervals_container.remove($.intervals_container.children[((_viewCount - 1) - s)]);
   }
}
```

Comment: This will remove all the views (including the one I couldn't remove before) however how can I remove just the one view? I've updated my question with what I tried but it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

First is why not simply call

```
$.intervals_container.remove(booking_view);
```

I dont think you need to go through the hassle of children and children length.
That should work
If it doesn't can you try changing the scrollview layout (height, width,left...) and see if that changes something? (might be a layout update issue).

As a side note you should hold a reference of "children". Every time you access it it needs to make a copy natively. Plus there is a lock there so it might get long.

Comment: I tried that originally and it doesn't work. It does match the view of a child container but that just doesn't remove it. The view in question is added into the view at a later time from the rest.

Comment: I must say i don't use alloy. But if you have a sample code that shows your problem (from add to remove), then i could try it and even fix the SDK bug if there's one. Let me know